# Show page_action icon always

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm brand new to Chrome extensions, but I wanted to start messing around with them for the fun of it. I know that it is against convention to always display a `page_action` icon, however for the purpose of learning I'd like to display it for every tab.

I've been doing reading and I'm having a hard time figuring out what's deprecated and what's not. The docs don't seem to note that some methods are deprecated.

Here's what I have so far -- it's been a while since I've messed with Javascript so bear with me; this is all very simple stuff.

So what would be the easiest way to always show a `page_action` icon? Am I even close to the right track?  Thanks.

---

*manifest.json*

```
{
"manifest_version" : 2,

"name": "Hello World",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Hello World",

"page_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/blackWhite.jpg", 
    "default_title": "HW!"
  },

"background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
 }
}
```

---

*background.js*

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab {
  var id = tab.id
  chrome.pageAction.show(id)
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would execute only once, while it should execute on every tab update.

One approach to do so is to listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, as done in a [sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/mappy/background.js).

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
  if (change.status == "complete") {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
});
```

This will make the page action appear when the page finishes loading.

If you want it to appear sooner, you can, for instance, listen to `onUpdated`, `onCreated` and `onReplaced` without filters (you don't care if you call `show()` several times).

**Edit:** Actually, another good combination is `onUpdated` (to detect URL change) and `onActivated` (to detect tab change).

Or, you can employ a content script that loads in all pages at `document_start` and messages the background to show the page action.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added your code to test, and I still don't get any icon showing up. I set a breakpoint in the debugger and sent a random request and the `change.status` value is `loading` instead of `complete` so I'm guessing that's why the icon doesn't show up? Because it's trying to load it too early?

Comment: "complete" should fire when the spinner on the tab stops.

Comment: I'm dumb. Had 'completed' instead of 'complete' ... Also, do chrome extensions support .jpg icons? An icon shows up, but it's not the one I specified.